# Copy lightning experience background look and feel

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, lightning-design-system, slds

I am developing a community and I would like it to look like lightning experience.

One main thing is the background picture that is dissolving into blue - I want to achieve a background like this:

[image]

So far I could get to this background:

[image]

with this code:

**MARKUP:**

```
<div class="allMainContainer">
    <div class="lex_background">
        This is my main component...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.THIS.allMainContainer {
    background-color: rgb(175, 197, 222);
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
.THIS .lex_background {
    background-image: url(/_slds/images/themes/oneSalesforce/banner-brand-default.png?cache=210.2);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top left;
}
```

But as you can see - the background does not look nice

**QUESTION:**

How can I make my background to look exactly like Lightning experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve the look you desire, you can use the built-in [Brand Band component](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/brand-band/) from the Lightning Design System by adding `extends="force:slds"` to your lightning app, which it appears you already have done, but there's a trick.

First off, you're going to want to add the 3 following classes to your wrapper (where you have placed the class `allMainContainer`): `slds-brand-band`, `slds-brand-band_cover`, & `slds-brand-band_medium`. This will give us the correct sizing and positioning for the Brand Band pseudo-elements.

Unfortunately, it seems that the SLDS import is completely unbranded (I tried to find documentation on changing that, unsuccessfully), which means we haven't yet accomplished anything noticeable with this import. Next, we'll want to add a few CSS declarations to get things to actually appear. These are all based on the actual declarations in the Lightning Experience for the Lightning Blue theme that you wanted to copy.

```css
.THIS.slds-brand-band {
    background-color: rgba(176, 196, 223, 1.0); /* This is the standard blue */
    z-index: 1; /* This is to counteract the -1 that the :before element has */
}

/* These are the gradients and image used in the Salesforce theme */
.THIS.slds-brand-band:before {
    background-image: url(/_slds/images/themes/lightning_blue/lightning_blue_background.png),linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 0, rgba(160, 180, 206, 1.0));
}
.THIS.slds-brand-band:after {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(176, 196, 223, 0.0) 60%, rgba(176, 196, 223, 1.0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a couple of things such as the height and the [gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) at the very least. All of these can be checked using your browsers developer tool.

Since the SF LEX branding/styling is not really documented (As far as i know) you will pretty much have to figure out the scoping and style applied for the look and feel to be similar.

Comment: What I have done already (code in the question) was with the dev-tools, but I cannot find how to make it look more like the standard way - my question asks for the missing parts  which I cannot find.